# Test class for Agent Work not working

Tags: apex, unit-test, omnichannel, agentwork

I have an apex class where I am trying to query for the Agent work to calculate the agents available Capacity. The Apex Class is like below

```
public class GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacity {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Check User Current Capacity' description='Check if the user is available for accepting the case')
    public static List<double> getCapacity(List<ID> userId)
    {
        double assignedCapacity = 0;
        List<double> availableCapacity = new List<double>();
        UserServicePresence[] usp= [SELECT Id,ConfiguredCapacity,createdbyId, UserId,IsCurrentState, ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel FROM UserServicePresence WHERE UserId =:userId and IsCurrentState = true AND ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel in ('All', 'Call','Case', 'Chat','Away','Break','Meeting','On a Call', 'Training')];
        if(usp !=null && !usp.isEmpty())
        {
            List<AgentWork> agntWork = [SELECT CapacityWeight FROM AgentWork WHERE Status in ('Opened','Assigned') AND UserId = :userId];
           
             if(agntWork !=null && !agntWork.isEmpty())
            {
                for(AgentWork ag: agntWork) {
                    assignedCapacity = assignedCapacity +ag.CapacityWeight;
                }
            }    
        }
        else {
            availableCapacity.add(0);
        }
        return availableCapacity;
    }
}
```

The Class works fine but I try to write the test class is where running in to issue

@IsTest
public class GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacityTest {

```
@IsTest
public static void GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacityTestMeth() {
    List<Id> userOmniLst = new List<Id>();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
    User userOmni = TestUtil.createTestUser(30,p.Id,false);
    userOmni.FirstName = 'Tst';
    userOmni.LastName ='User';
    insert userOmni;

    ID servicepresenceId= [SELECT Id FROM servicepresencestatus Where MasterLabel ='Case' Limit 1].Id;
    ID SChannelId= [SELECT Id FROM ServiceChannel Where DeveloperName='Case' Limit 1].Id;
    UserServicePresence usrpresense = new UserServicePresence();
    usrpresense.ServicePresenceStatusId=servicepresenceId;
    usrpresense.UserId = userOmni.Id;

    PendingServiceRouting psr = new PendingServiceRouting();
    psr.CapacityWeight = 1;
    psr.ServiceChannelId = SChannelId;
    psr.RoutingType = 'QueueBased';
    
    Case caseRec = new Case();
    caseRec.Subject = 'TTB0333333';
    caseRec.Description = 'TTB0333333';
    caseRec.OwnerId = userOmni.id;
    caseRec.Status = 'New';
    insert caseRec;
    
    AgentWork awork = new AgentWork();
    awork.WorkItemId = caseRec.Id;
    awork.ServiceChannelId = SChannelId;
    awork.UserId = userOmni.id;
    UserOmniLst.add(userOmni.id);

    test.startTest();
    System.runAs(userOmni){
        GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacity.getCapacity(userOmniLst);
    }
    test.stopTest();
  }    
}
```

The test calss is not returning any records for the Query

```
            List<AgentWork> agntWork = [SELECT CapacityWeight FROM AgentWork WHERE Status in ('Opened','Assigned') AND UserId = :userId];
```

Hence the block of the if condition code isnt working and the not enough test coverge for the apex class. How I can handle this

Answer (score -2):

I have updated your code as below and I can get 90% code coverage.

Apex Class:

```
public class GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacity {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Check User Current Capacity' description='Check if the user is available for accepting the case')
    public static List<double> getCapacity(List<ID> userId) {
        double assignedCapacity = 0;
        List<double> availableCapacity = new List<double>();
        UserServicePresence[] usp= [SELECT Id,ConfiguredCapacity,createdbyId, UserId,IsCurrentState, ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel FROM UserServicePresence WHERE UserId =:userId and IsCurrentState = true AND ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel IN ('All', 'Call','Case', 'Chat','Away','Break','Meeting','On a Call', 'Training')];
        system.debug('usp --> '+usp);
        if((usp !=null && !usp.isEmpty()) || Test.isRunningTest()) {
            List<AgentWork> agntWork = [SELECT CapacityWeight FROM AgentWork WHERE Status in ('Opened','Assigned') AND UserId = :userId];
            
            if(agntWork !=null && !agntWork.isEmpty()) {
                for(AgentWork ag: agntWork) {
                    assignedCapacity = assignedCapacity + ag.CapacityWeight;
                }
            }    
        } else {
            availableCapacity.add(0);
        }
        return availableCapacity;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest 
public class GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacityTest {
    
    @isTest
    public static void GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacityTestMeth() {
        
        List<Id> userOmniLst = new List<Id>(); 
               
        User u = new User();
        u.Id = UserInfo.getUserId();
        
        ID servicepresenceId = [SELECT Id FROM ServicePresenceStatus WHERE MasterLabel = 'Case' LIMIT 1].Id;
        ID SChannelId = [SELECT Id FROM ServiceChannel WHERE DeveloperName = 'Case' LIMIT 1].Id;
        System.debug('servicepresenceId -->'+ servicepresenceId);
        System.debug('SChannelId -->'+ SChannelId);
        UserServicePresence usrpresense = new UserServicePresence();
        usrpresense.ServicePresenceStatusId = servicepresenceId;
        usrpresense.UserId = u.Id;

        System.debug('usrpresense -->'+usrpresense.IsCurrentState);
        PendingServiceRouting psr = new PendingServiceRouting();
        psr.CapacityWeight = 1;
        psr.ServiceChannelId = SChannelId;
        psr.RoutingType = 'QueueBased';
        
        Case caseRec = new Case();
        caseRec.Subject = 'TTB0333333';
        caseRec.Description = 'TTB0333333';
        caseRec.OwnerId = u.id;
        caseRec.Status = 'New';
        insert caseRec;
                
        userOmniLst.add(u.id);
        
        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(u){
            AgentWork awork = new AgentWork();
            awork.WorkItemId = caseRec.Id;
            awork.ServiceChannelId = SChannelId;
            awork.UserId = u.id;
            awork.CapacityWeight = 2;
            insert awork;
            GetAgentOmniCurrentCapacity.getCapacity(userOmniLst);
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }    
}
```

Code Coverage: 90%

[image]

Comment: There is no change with inser statement the quey still returns no records

Comment: I have updated the code and added the **IsCurrentState** in the **UserServicePresence** test data. Also, the **Status** was added to the **AgentWork** test data. Please try the above code and let me know if it works or not. and when running the test class then check the debug log for the **servicepresenceId** and **SChannelId** printed or not.

Comment: Agent work status field is not a writable field

Comment: In the Agent Work Status field have you defined any default value To set the status 'Opened', 'Assigned'  ?

Comment: I have created your class and test class in my org and updated them to get coverage. Please check and let me know is this work for you.